# Installing a Monitoring Agent on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm trying to install a Monitoring Agent on my f1-micro instance with Debian 9 and running dockerised application. I'm following the https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent#linux-install tutorial. When I execute `sudo bash install-monitoring-agent.sh` I get a message `Unidentifiable or unsupported platform.`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Do check which shell you're using. Is it bash or ksh or anything else. If it's not bash, then change the last command which you're using.

Comment: I've checked. It's bash

Answer (score 0):

Inside the bash script you will see that he looking on the os-release on [/etc/os-release] see below:

============================================================================

```
# Fallback for systems lacking /etc/os-release.
      if [[ -f /etc/debian_version ]]; then
        echo 'Installing agent for Debian.'
        install_for_debian
      elif [[ -f /etc/redhat-release ]]; then
        echo 'Installing agent for Red Hat.'
        install_for_redhat
      else
        echo >&2 'Unidentifiable or unsupported platform.'
        echo >&2 "See ${MONITORING_AGENT_SUPPORTED_URL} for a list of supported platforms."
        exit 1
```

Check the [/etc/os-release].
Normally Debian its supported, and I did install {f1-micro} machine with Debian and it worked perfectly, the output should be like below:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just realised that google runs docker images only on "Container-Optimized OS from Google" and monitoring engine doesn't support this OS.